# Confused about strings in Java

Tags: java, string, boolean

I've recently started learning Java and I was fooling around and I got confused on this.

```
String s1 = "Happy";
String s2 = "Happy";
String s3 = new String ("Happy");

boolean sameString;
sameString = (s1 == s2);
System.out.println("s1 == s2 is " + sameString);
// This returns True.

sameString = (s1 == s3);
System.out.println("s1 == s3 is " + sameString);
// This returns False.
```

Can someone explain why this is so to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

```
String s1="Happy";
String s2="Happy";
if(s1==s2) ===> true
```

**(s1==s2) ===> true**

```
                   String Pool
s1 -----------------> "Happy" <-----------------s2
```

**if(s1==s3) ===> false.**

```
            String Pool
"Happy" <-------------------- s1

               Heap
"Happy" <-------------------- s3
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in java are immutable 
it means that when you change the string java will create a new memory location
when you write String s1 = "Happy" you give the java the control to make the
 string for you
if java finds any string that have the same value suppose you write s2 = "Happy"
it will make s1 and s2 points at the same memory location 
so s1 == s2 will return true
but when you write String s3 = new String("Happy"); you make a new memory  location 

 
when you write s3 == s2 it will return false bec s2 and s3 are in different memory locations